# Tor has stopped working

Tags: network-configuration

Tor browser has stopped working ( windows 10 ) worked ok but has suddenly stopped opening.! Have reinstalled it twice but it will not open.? task manager shows no tor process running.? Help please.

Comment: Check your anti-virus, and windows application event logs for anything relating to `firefox.exe`, `tor.exe` or `Tor Browser` and let us know what the logs say if you find any. You should also try disabling or uninstalling `Trusteer Rapport` if you have it.